# TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html After dividing settings.py into 3seperate files

Tags: python, django

I was working on a Django project.

my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index')
]
```

my `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

in my `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(BASE_DIR / "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Till this point, all works perfectly**, the template also rendered as it should. Now I approach to divide my `settings.py` into 3 separate files for my production purpose like:

```
Settings (Folder)
  | base.py
  | development.py
  | production.py
```

Here the `base.py` contains almost all necessary settings, `development.py` and `production.py` inherit the `base.py` and have only `allowed host` and `debug` values. `development.py` and `production.py` are also properly hooked up with `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` file of the project.

Now after this work it shows me an error like:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html
```

I also try with

```
def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the diagnosis index.")
```

It also works perfectly! maybe it only has problem with template/Base dir. Please suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you put the `index.html` template?

Comment: inside `templates` folder. `templates` folder is located at that folder where `manage.py` also placed

Comment: Add your app to installed apps

Comment: Add your app to installed apps

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally inside `settings.py` we have address of `BASE_DIR` which become changed after creating the file `base.py` inside `settings` folder. We need to modify it like:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
```

The extra one `.parent` helps it find the root

Answer (score 0):

In front the file name, add the app name:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/index.html')
```